# populate NSArray Json data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutabledictionary

I have this code and need to get the key value **nombre** and populate a NSArray *array but not work

```
NSURL *urlPaises = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tr.com.mx/prb2/buscarPais.php"];
NSData *dataPaises = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlPaises];

    NSArray *array;

    NSMutableDictionary *jsonPaises;
    NSError *error;

    array = [[NSArray alloc]init];


        jsonPaises = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataPaises options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        array = [jsonPaises objectForKey: @"nombre"];


        Printing description of self->jsonPaises:
        {
            paises =     (
                        {
                    id = 49;
                    nombre = Alemania;
                },
                        {
                    id = 54;
                    nombre = Argentina;
                },

                        {
                    id = 44;
                    nombre = Inglaterra;
                },

                        {
                    id = 598;
                    nombre = Uruguay;
                },
                        {
                    id = 58;
                    nombre = Venezuela;
                }
            );
        }
```

Comment: Aww, lots of problems. First, you are leaking memory by overwriting the allocated `NSMutableArray` pointer. That's not how memory management works. Second, you can clearly see that the object is an array, so it won't for the heck of it respond to `objectForKey:`. If you can't deduce yourself that you need a loop to solve this, then you should probably learn a bit more about algorithms, data structures and programming in general before trying to deep dive into iOS development. (Learn in small steps - do yourself a favor.)

Comment: @H2CO3 I think he is trying to access the dictionary and parse its results into an array. Im pretty sure he can use `valueForKeyPath` without the need for a loop - though I could have misinterpreted his question.

Comment: @OliverAtkinson Well, maybe yes. Still, not knowing the solution for this problem indicates that there are some fundamental knowledge missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to use `valueForKeyPath`

```
[jsonPaises valueForKeyPath:@"praises.nombre"]
```

Should return an array of the `nombres`

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly =)

[array addObject:[jsonPaises valueForKeyPath: @"paises.nombre"]];

Answer (score 0):

`jsonPaises` is an array. Arrays have indexes `0,1,2` not keys `"apple","foo","bar"`. Asking an array the value for a key will never work. You have an array of dictionaries. 
If what you want is a new array with the value of the key "nombre" for every dictionary in you original array then try this:

```
NSMutableArray * newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //create the new array
for (NSDictionary * dict in array) {  //for each dictionary in the first array
    id object = dict[@"nombre"]; //get the object stored in the key
    if(object) { //check that the key/value was actually in the dict
         [newArray addObject:object]; //add the object to the new Array
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific is the value for key @"nombre" coming as a single name or it's an array of names? I will guess it's an array of names then try:

```
for (NSString *name in [jsonPaises objectForKey:@"nombre"]) {
      NSLog("%@", name);
}
```

if the value for key @"nombre" is  single string then you add it to the array as:

```
[array addObject:[jsonPaises objectForKey: @"nombre"]];
```